# Using yield WaitForSeconds() in a function returning void

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, wait, void, yield-return

I have a jumpscare in my game. I am using Unity 3D.
My first function is

```
public void ScareMe(Vector3 pos) {
    //it does some necessary irrelevant 
    //stuff and then it invokes another function
    Invoke ("Smile",.2f);
}
```

In my other function I want to make an object appear and then disappear in 0.2 ms. 
I use

```
 IEnumerator Smile() {
     Object.SetActive(true);
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
     Object.SetActive(false);
 }
```

But for some reason my function Smile is never invoked as long as it returns something other then void.

Is there any way to use something like yield but go around it so I don't have to return anything?
I was thinking a while loop like a coroutine? But I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Uhm...  `Thread.Sleep(ms)`.

Comment: Sounds like [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It will better if you can explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It doesn't let me use Thread.Sleep(); It says "Thread" does not exist in a current context

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to achieve (and why) rather than telling us that how you've tried to solve it doesn't work? It may well be that there is a different way of approaching the problem but we can only help with that if we know what the actual problem is.

Comment: I edited it. Let me know if you need more info

Comment: Please show us a _concise_ example of the _whole_ method and how you want to call it, and explain precisely what you want it to do. Even better, provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for additional advice. Please be more specific than "doesn't work". State exactly what happens and how that's different from what you want to happen.

Comment: Does that have to be in iterator blocks? Otherwise you can use `await Task.Delay(1000);`. If this doesn't help, give us some more context.

Comment: It doesn't recognize await Task.Delay() either....

Comment: -_- aaand this is how it always happens with stack overflow. You get 5+ comments about how to make your question sound right, but then you edit it and no answers to the actual question whatsoever. ok.

Comment: I don't know what you're whining about, all of your other questions appear to have answers.  Also, of the 5 comments (now 6) that aren't made by you, 3 of them are trying to help.

Comment: @Dan-o - unity runs on single thread - so Thread.Sleep() will just put your whole game to pause mode for given amount of time. I believe proper syntax how to invoke "Smile" is yield return StartCoroutine(Smile());

Comment: thanks @OndrejSvejdar, i was unaware unity is single threaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Unity's Invoke(func) is only willing to start a coroutine in Javascript, where the difference between a void and a coroutine is less strict.

What I would do is use `StartCoroutine(Smile());` and start Smile with another `yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);`, or better yet have Smile take a `float smileDelay` parameter and use that for your WaitForSeconds.